# Validation.Modify method does not work with dynamic range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a field (cell C20) validated by dynamic lists basing on selection in cell C18.

I have a list of countries and related data (country in 1st row, data following). The idea is that when you select country in one cell, the validation list in other.

The macro goes through all cells in row 1 and when value matches selected one, it shall modify the validation list.

The code crashes on the Validation.Modify method, at the end (error 1004, application defined, or object defined error). Rows and columns are identified correctly.

I tried puting variables directly in this line and generating them in separate string, nothing of this works.

Could you please advise me what am I doing wrong?

```
Dim countryList As Range
Dim countrySel As String
Dim ctrListRow As Integer
Dim ctrAdress As String
Dim ctrCol As String
Dim ctrAdrInt As Integer
Dim ctrDolFind As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim valRng As String
    
countrySel = ctr

For Each countryList In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("locIDs").Range("A1:CD1")
    
    If countryList.Value = countrySel Then
        ctrAdress = countryList.Address
        ctrAdrInt = Len(ctrAdress)
        ctrAdress = Right(ctrAdress, ctrAdrInt - 1)
        ctrDolFind = InStr(1, ctrAdress, "$")
        ctrCol = Left(ctrAdress, ctrDolFind - 1)
        lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("locIDs").Range(ctrCol & ":" & ctrCol).Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        
        Debug.Print "ctrCol: " & ctrCol
        Debug.Print "lastRow: " & lastRow
        
        valRng = "=$" & ctrCol & "$2:$" & ctrCol & "$" & lastRow
        
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Checklist").Range("C20").Validation.Modify xlValidateList, xlValidAlertStop, valRng
    End If
    
Next countryList
```

Comment: Missing third parameter in `Validation.Modify`. `Formula1` is the fourth parameter. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Validation.Modify